# Displaying data from a mysql server on a datagridview object. is not displaying anything

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have tried making a dataset using the dataset tool to link it on the design side however that hasn't worked as it keeps disappearing and this is the other way it does not display any values on the datagrid view i am unsure why and i am fairly new to this side of vb so if you could explain it as well that would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Search
    Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            If TextBox1.Text = "" Then 'this acts as a simple presence check on the textbox
            Else
                Dim val = "name"
                If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then 'This changes the type of search i do as it filters which column the query looks in
                    val = "type"
                End If
                Await getDataSet(TextBox1.Text) ' waits for infomation to be retrieved
            End If
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) 'Catches any errors 
        End Try
    End Sub

    Async Function getDataSet(partname As String) As Task(Of DataSet) 'This retrieves the values that matches the users input 
        Return Await Task.Factory.StartNew(
    Function()
        Dim connectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=; database=partstest1; CharSet=utf8;" 'These are the login details for the database in the form of a connection string 
        Dim commandText = "SELECT ID, Benchpoint, Name, Type, BrandID FROM `parts` WHERE `name` Like  '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%';"
        Using connDB = New MySqlConnection(connectionString), objCmd = New MySqlCommand(), objAdpt = New MySqlDataAdapter()
            connDB.Open()
            objCmd.Connection = connDB
            objCmd.CommandText = commandText
            objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text 'These lines specify the command i am using and execute it
            objAdpt.SelectCommand = objCmd
            Dim objDs = New DataSet()
            objAdpt.Fill(objDs) 'Puts all of the values into a dataset
            PartsDataGridView.DataSource = objDs.Tables(0) 'This shows the datasource and displays it
            Console.WriteLine(objDs)
            Return objDs
        End Using
    End Function)
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Install MySQL/connector/etc
- Install MySQL for Visual Studio (needed to get it to show as a datasource in VS) - https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/
- Add a new dataset to your project
  [image]
- Double click the dataset, right click the surface of it, choose Add >> TableAdapter
  [image]
- Choose existing connection or New Connection if you have no existing. Choose MySQL Database (install MySQL for Visual Studio from step 2 if this is absent)
  [image]
- Enter server details, choose to save the password, back in the wizard choose **Yes, include sensitive..** and click **Next**, choose **Yes, save the connection string**, click **Next**,  choose **Use SQL Statements**, **Next**, enter a suitable query that selects based on the primary key such as `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE id = @id`, **Next**, call the methods *FillById* and *GetDataById* to distinct them from other queries you may add later like *FillByCity* or *GetDataByStatus*. At the end of this wizard you should have a datatable and tableadapter that looks like your database table:
  [image]
- Switch to the form designer, and also ensure that the *Data Sources* window is visible (click **View Menu** >> **Other Windows** >> *Data Sources**), expand all the nodes in the Data Sources panel
  [image]
- Drag the node representing your table (mine is called *person*) out of the datasources window and drop it on the form. Several things will appear:

  - a datagridview already bound to the dataset's datatable showing person data,
  - a toolstrip with a textbox for inputting the ID (remember you made a query that takes a parameter),
  - another toolstrip with navigators and a save button),
  - a dataset (needed to store the data),
  - a bindingsource (acts as a link between the dataset's datatable and the grid, knows what current record is showing, allows sorting and filtering),
  - a tableadapter (an enhanced data adapter that will pull data from the db into the dataset and send back any changes),
  - a tableadapter manager (a device that knows what order to run updates in for hierarchical data)

[image]

- Also, as a demonstration of how it works, drag all the nodes UNDERNEATH person onto the form also - you can see they have different icons. They will re-use most of the components on the form but you'll get textboxes, datetimepickers, checkboxes etc that are bound to the bindingsource and will hence show the current item from the underlying list (the datagridview shows them all, with an indicator of which row is current)

[image]

- Run the project, type an ID into the textbox, hit **FillById*, write some new info into another row at the bottom - it will commit to the underlying dataset/datatable when you change row in the DGV, note that flicking back and forth between the rows in the DGV causes the textboxes to change as the notion of *Current* row is updated (navigating the grid, or clicking the arrows in the navigator changes the bindingsource .`Current` property, and all controls bind through the bindingsource

[image]

- hit save - now go look in your db in MySQL Workbench - the new record is there. You've made a full databound UI, and not written a line of code - all the code is there in the FormX.vb if you want to see it - written for you by the designer. Take a look

> Note that it still says -4 (in my UI) for the temp id; the program didn't download the new ID that was assigned by the DB. To make it do this, youre supposed to be able to go back to your dataset, right click the tableadapter, click **Advanced Options**, and tick on *Refresh the datatable* - this will cause the adapter to update any local IDs after it saves the row. IDs can cascade update if they are part of a datarelation between two datetables. In MySQL this doesn't work (I'm reporting a bug to them now), but you can make it work by manually editing the XML file representing the dataset (right click the DataSet in solution explorer, choose **Open With**.. Choose **XML Editor**, locate the insert statement eg:

```
INSERT INTO `person` (`Name`, `Birthdate`, `Salary`) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3)
```

Add another statement after it so it looks like:

```
INSERT INTO `person` (`Name`, `Birthdate`, `Salary`) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3)
;SELECT `Id`, `Name`, `Birthdate`, `Salary` FROM `person` WHERE `Id` = last_insert_id()
```

Now, saving the table will cause the UI to refresh with the ID values calculated by the auto increment in the DB

Comment: Yes this worked and thank you for explaining it i understand how it works now