# It tellw me update success without adding the data to ms access database file

Tags: vb.net

This reports update success without adding the data to MS Access database file

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DatabaseDataSet.Table1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Table1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.DatabaseDataSet.Table1)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
        dataFile = "C:\Users\police\Documents\database.accdb"
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "update Table1 set [ProductName] ='" & TextBox2.Text & "', [Qty] ='" & TextBox3.Text & "', [Price] ='" & TextBox4.Text & "'  where [ID] = " & TextBox1.Text & ""
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        MsgBox("Update Success")

        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myConnection.Close()
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()
            TextBox3.Clear()
            TextBox4.Clear()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Um, maybe you should try executing the command before declaring success. Apart from that, what value is returned by `ExecuteNonQuery`? That will tell you whether it was successful or not. Like so many other people using a local data file, you're probably just looking in the wrong place and/or at the wrong time.

Comment: Also, why are you calling `ExecuteNonQuery` at all? You have a typed `DataSet` that you are populating on `Load`. You're supposed to use that save data too. You should spend some time learning how to use a typed `DataSet`.

Comment: How to use a typed dataset (this is mysql but the technique is virtually the same as access, just a different db provider): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61058314/displaying-data-from-a-mysql-server-on-a-datagridview-object-is-not-displaying/61078006#61078006

Answer (score 0):

The comments above offer the best solution but, for whatever reason, if you want to write your own update command you can do it as follows.

Keep your database objects local to the method where they are used. `Using...End Using` blocks can then assure that your objects are closed and disposed. Always use parameters to guard against sql injection and make you query easier to write. In Access the order that the parameters appear in the sql statement must match the order that they are added to the Parameters collection. I had to guess at the datatypes of the parameters in the `.Add` method. Check your database for the actual types and adjust the code. The values in the text boxes should be validated before you reach this step but I just converted them on a wish and a prayer.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\police\Documents\database.accdb"

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using myConnection As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("update Table1 set [ProductName] = @ProdName, [Qty] = @Qty, [Price] = @Price  where [ID] = @ID;", myConnection)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@ProdName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
            .Add("@Qty", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(TextBox3.Text)
            .Add("@Price", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = CDec(TextBox4.Text)
            .Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
        End With
        Try
            myConnection.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using
    MsgBox("Update Success")
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
    TextBox3.Clear()
    TextBox4.Clear()
End Sub
```